# Python: Formatting the way my program writes arrays to txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to get my program to print one item from each array to a text file and then once all the first items were written,write the second item of the array on the second line and so on.

The code I have now only prints the info on one line of text.

```
def write():
    outFile=open("Inventory.txt","w")
    for i in range(0,len(clothesItem)):
            outFile.write(format(clothesItem[i],ITEM_FORMAT)+format(clothesColor[i],COLOR_FORMAT)+format(clothesAmount[i],AMOUNT_FORMAT))
    outFile.close()
```

Comment: To write text with multiple lines, use the newline character, "\n".

Comment: Where would I put the \n. I can't put it in the outFile.write

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

> ```
> outFile.write(format(clothesItem[i],ITEM_FORMAT)+format(clothesColor[i],COLOR_FORMAT)+format(clothesAmount[i],AMOUNT_FORMAT))
> ```

To the following:

```
outFile.write(format(clothesItem[i], ITEM_FORMAT) + format(clothesColor[i],COLOR_FORMAT) + format(clothesAmount[i], AMOUNT_FORMAT) + "\n")
                                                                                                                                     ^^^^
```

Note the `+ "\n"` added onto the end.